# D3 Zoom TypeError: t.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Currently, i'm trying to implement a zoom function to my data visualization. Sometimes an error occurs "d3.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: t.apply is not a function" when i try to zoom or to move the svg element. It looks like an internal error within d3 library.

```
var height = $("#content").height();
var width = $("#content").width();

var svg = d3.select("#content").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "svg_canvas")
            .append("g")
                .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2.0) + "," + (height /2.0 )+ ")")
            .append("g")
                .attr("class", "interaction_group");

        zoom_layer = svg;

        //Overlay for zooming
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-width / 2.0) + "," + -(height/2.0 ) + ")");
```

The event handler "zoom" is really basic:

```
function zoom() {
        zoom_layer.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");     
    }
```

The implementation was realized with the latest D3.js **V3** version.

Comment: Very difficult unless you put a fiddle...

Comment: You are right. I analyzed the error more in detail and occures with an additional dependency. I added also zoom.js as a plugin of reveal.js. The d3 zoom function and zoom.js doesn't work together.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declare your zoom behavior:

```
var myZoomBehavior=d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom)
```

Then call it to the svg root:

```
var svg = d3.select("#content").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("class", "svg_canvas").call(myZoomBehavior)
```

Then create the zoomable g with the same variable name as in your zoom function:

```
var zoom_layer=svg.append("g")
```